# Copy data into sheet if cell = value, works only sometimes?

Tags: excel, vba

If a cell in column E = "Y", then I want to copy that cell's entire row into Sheet 2, and do this for each worksheet in the workbook, except Sheet 2.

Here's the code I've tried.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cpyrow As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
    For Each cell In Range("E:E")
        If cell.Value = "Y" Then
            lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            cpyrow = cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row
            ws.Range(cpyrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastrow)
        End If
        Next cell
    End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Sometimes it will copy the correct row, but other times it will copy rows whose cell in column E doesn't equal "Y", or it will skip over rows that do. Also why does it give different results when I run it while I'm on different sheets? Shouldn't it run the same and go through every worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

You missed a parent sheet reference on the loop:

> `For Each cell In Range("E:E")`

Should be

```
For Each cell In ws.Range("E:E")
```

Other wise you are testing the active sheet but copying the correct sheet on that row.

Comment: wow that solved everything, thanks! can't believe I missed that

Comment: I have a follow up question, why does lastrow = 1 even when the sheet is empty? I want it to start at 0.

Comment: @KaylaTran there is no row 0, so it will always be 1 with xlup on an empty sheet.

Comment: if I remove "+ 1" from lastrow, it always equals 1 and doesn't update. How would I get the code to start pasting from row 1 and continue, because it starts pasting at row 2.

Comment: if I remove "+ 1" from lastrow, it always equals 1 and doesn't update. How would I get the code to start pasting from row 1 and continue, because it starts pasting at row 2.

Comment: You will need to test what it is. In place of the `+1` put `+ IIF(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row>1,1,0)`

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
For Each cell In Range("E:E")
```

with:

```
For Each cell In ws.Range("E:E")
```

*(there may be other errors)*

Comment: Well............you know what the say about great minds....................

Comment: @ScottCraner  Amen to that..................especially if the error is apparent by visual inspection.........